# Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' won't reset after repair

Tags: php, webserver, error-logging

I'm using Eclipse to work with my php site.  It originally worked very well under Linux, but then I re-installed it to a Windows based server.  Now I get the error above.  The original line causing the error was:

```
php?>
```

but I changed it to:

```
?>
```

My problem is, I'm still getting the same error across the board on every site I go to (it's in my header.php file), no matter how many times I refresh or reboot.  Not sure why it's not evaluating it fresh, but I know that it's not, because there is no more 'php' in the offending line.

I'm thinking I need to have my php server reset the error log or something, but not sure how to do that.  Any suggestions are welcome.

-Tano

Comment: On the line of that error, what is the exact code?

Comment: what webserver are you using in windows?

Comment: -On that line the exact code is ?>

Comment: tomexsans- I'm using XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out what the problem was, and it still makes no sense, but at least I know where to look.

I'm using eclipse to edit my PHP files.  In eclipse, the changes are taking effect.  Even if I exit, reboot, and restart eclipse, that darn 'php' is gone.

[image: proof that I fixed it]

But, when i actually load the "C:\xampp\www\MyLibraryAnywhere\scripts\header.php" file in Notepad++ I can see the stinkin' "php" is still there!

So, the issue is that edits made in eclipse are not being saved to the actual files in question.  I made the repair in Notepad++ and the error is gone now.  I'll post to the eclipse board to see why this is happening.

Thanks to all that took the time to help me.

Comment: Interesting. Were you possibly editing the wrong file in Eclipse? A copy of it?